# "I entered the classroom during the lesson. Students were paying attention."

Tags: grammar, definite-article

*"I entered the classroom during the lesson. Students were paying attention."*

Here the first sentence gives enough information that there must be students there.
And then I introduce them in the second sentence.

1) Is it correct usage?

2) What will be the difference from saying "the students"?

3) I understand no article can mean introducing some of the students there, but can mean all, so it's vague but acceptable, however when I mean roughly all, saying with no article as an introduction here  would be unnatural.

Do I feel it right?

Please, help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversation beneath your answer is getting a little long, so let me add something here:

> *"There were people there. People were nice." - is not grammatical*.

True, because you've already mentioned the people. You need to say, "**The** people were nice", meaning, "The people [in that location] were nice."

> *"I entered the police station. The officers were looking at me" = those who were at the room I entered, not all over the building, were looking it me?*

Yes, of course, it means the officers in the room – not every officer in the squadron, or every officer in the city, or every officer on duty that day.

> *"I entered the classroom during the lesson. Students were paying attention."*
>
> The first sentence gives enough information that there must be students there. And then I introduce them in the second sentence. Is it correct usage? What will be the difference from saying "the students"?

It's correct either way, although leaving the article out is usually interpreted as:

> *[Some] students were paying attention*     (i.e., most, or all, or half, or a few)

whereas when you say "the students," it's generally assumed:

> *[All or most] students were paying attention*     (i.e., most, or all, or half, if not a bit more than half)

That is, **as a group**, the students were paying attention.

> *can "the students", "the officers", if there are more of them who were paying attention/looking at me than those who didn't do that in a place, mean "most of them", so there can be some exceptions?*

Absolutely! Now you're getting it!

> I walked into the library. The people were looking at me.

Indicates that a lot of the people were looking at you. Maybe all of them, but, then again, maybe there's one sullen teenager in the corner who can't pry his eyes out of his sci-fi book, or one librarian who is too busy shelving books to notice you. If you really want to emphasize that every set of eyes was on you, you can say:

> I walked into the library. All the people were looking at me.

or:

> I walked into the library. Everyone was looking at me.

Even in that last case, though, we need to leave room for hyperbole. For example:

> Everyone was drunk at the bar.

is often uttered, when what the native speaker really means is:

> A lot of people were drunk at the bar.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. It is really helpful a lot! I hope this time my commentaries won't last long... :) I have some examples seemed confusing: "I was in the forest. Trees were really dark, clouds were very white" - Everyone expects trees at the forest and understands there can be clouds on the sky there, can I introduce them as a first mention with zero article? Is it grammatical in such context?; and this one "I sat into a car. A driver was funny" - is it OK? Do these examples sound like talking down to?

Comment: _I was in the forest. The trees were really dark, the clouds were very white._ It sounds much better if you include the article, but omitting them does not result in incorrect English.

Comment: Thank you! If I omit them here, the meaning stays the same - it works as the first mention of all the trees/clouds there?

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes.
2. "The students" implies a specific group: *all* the students in the classroom. "Students" is a generic group; it's also not necessarily all students in the classroom.
3. To achieve that meaning, I would use "**Most of the students** were paying attention."

Comment: Thanks, mooseman. What do you mean by saying general group? I've never heard such a term. I thought that when we talk generally, we have no specific instances of a class in mind. Does "general group" mean "a group of specific instances, with no specified information of how many specific instances we include into the group" ?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You mean that "students" can be just a general group of any students, but can also be the first mention of unspecified in quantity group of particular students :) Got it?

Comment: @NikolayKomolov Exactly. "Students" = general group of unspecified quantity.

Comment: No, I don't understand :( General group = any in the world? So you mean above, that "students" = any/all/some/most in the world? Please, clarify. Thanks.

Comment: "Students" could mean 3 of "the students" or 30 of "the students".

Comment: Thanks. How can general group refer to real instances? Look here: "There were people there. People were nice" - it is not grammatically correct , this is what I was told once... For first mention it can be used, so in the example about students it seems correct...

Comment: Perhaps "Students will travel home for Christmas break." You wouldn't say "the students" because not _every_ student is travelling home

Comment: I get your point. I don't understand if it is natural to say "Students" in my example as the first mention of them, assuming I imply all? Would it be like as if I think the listener is not clever enough to understand who I talk about in that case? P.S. I know, maybe the question sounds insane :D

Comment: I get your question. I wouldn't worry over an article ("the") that reader may feel "talked down to".

Comment: I see, but what with "zero article" then? Again, is it correct to introduce all the students with zero article when the previous sentence makes it clear that there are students there? Isn't it "talking down to" ? :))

Comment: "is it correct to introduce all the students with zero article" No, I would use "The students" if you are addressing all the students.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. You've given me something to think about. :)

Comment: Sure, just one more clarification.. "I entered the police station. The officers were looking at me" = those who were at the room I entered, not all over the building, were looking it me?? Those, in that situation where I were? As here we expect there might some police officers at the entrance...

Comment: Thank You! Mooseman, could you please, tell me: can "the students", "the officers", if there are more of them who were paying attention/looking at me than those who didn't do that in a place, mean "most of them", so there can be some exceptions? I was told it often depends on a size of a group, is it true? (answers are so conflicing often...)

Comment: Oh, sorry, one more question. If it is clear that there can be only one teacher in a classroom, is it correct to introduce him this way? "I entered a classroom. A teacher was explaining things". Isn't it strange here?

Comment: "A teacher was explaining things" is entirely valid. Although I would recommend replacing "things" with a more concrete noun such as "the lesson".

Comment: Thanks! One thought stroke me - "I entered the classroom. Students were paying attention" - students are unspecified here, so can mean even all the students, but the listener will think otherwise. Is it correct? I think this is the last thing I want to clear out :)

Comment: It *can* mean all the students, but "the students" is more clear.

Comment: Thanks! Then why it is incorrect to say "students" in the second sentence when referring to them all? Because we already made it clear in the previous sentence that there will be students there, so no article in the second works like the second mention, therefore means some? And why if we know there can be only one teacher in the class, saying with "a teacher" is correct?

Comment: Let me make my question more clear:) Can the original sentence be used with "students" as the first mention, where it can refer even to all students and will it be correct grammatically with such a connotation? Does the connotion of the previous sentence allow this (I doubt because it has enough information that students will be there)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you put it all together?